Teams Toolkit: Unable to Implement ACTION.EXECUTE in Adaptive card
I working on a M365 copilot plugin implemented using Search Message Extension created by Teams ToolsKit(.Net).
I have Implemented two methods

protected override async Task<MessagingExtensionResponse> OnTeamsMessagingExtensionQueryAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, MessagingExtensionQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Which returns MessagingExtensionResponse consist of MessagingExtensionAttachment consist of AdaptiveCard

protected override async Task<AdaptiveCardInvokeResponse> OnAdaptiveCardInvokeAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, AdaptiveCardInvokeValue invokeValue, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Which will re-render the adaptive card through which ACTION.EXECUTE is been  invoked.
My issue is that because of The ACTION.EXECUTE, I am unable to send the Adaptive Card back to Teams & get any response back from the Adaptive Card.
What am I doing wrong? Am I missing any implementation or Permission?
With ACTION.EXECUTE
WithOut ACTION.EXECUTE
Here is the code snipet on my Adaptive Card
AdaptiveActionSet actionSet = new AdaptiveActionSet();
actionSet.Actions = [
          new AdaptiveExecuteAction()
            {
                   Verb="submit",
                   Title = "Submit",
                   Id="submitcard",
                            Fallback = new AdaptiveFallbackElement()
                            {
                                Content = new AdaptiveSubmitAction(),
                                Type= AdaptiveFallbackElement.AdaptiveFallbackType.Content
                            },
                   Data = new{
                           accountId="${accountId.value}",
                           closeDate="${closeDate.value}",
                           opportunityStage="${opportunityStage.value}",
                           opportunityType="${opportunityType.value}",
                           amount="${amount.value}",
                           leadSource="${leadSource}",
                       }
                    }
                ];


Without AdaptiveExecuteAction() I am able to send back the Card to Teams.
I also try AdaptiveSubmitAction() but bot didn't get any invoke.
My guess is Teams Toolkit Implement BOT different from BOT Framework


Refer this sample which uses action.execute in Adaptive Card- https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-all-cards/csharp/BotAllCards/Resources/adaptiveCard.json
